# Android Firebase Analytics: predefined and custom parameters not working

Tags: android, ios, firebase, cordova, firebase-analytics

I have application which use Firebase SDK and used some predefined event and parameters but some parameters are automatically added but not all parameters

**For example**  Add to cart event

**Android :**

```
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, params.get("item_category").toString());
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, params.get("item_name").toString());
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_LOCATION_ID, params.get("item_location_id").toString());
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CURRENCY, params.get("currency").toString());
bundle.putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, ((Number) params.get("value")).doubleValue());
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.COUPON, params.get("coupon").toString());
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, params.get("item_id").toString());
bundle.putLong(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.QUANTITY, ((Number) params.get("quantity")).longValue());
this.firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.ADD_TO_CART, bundle);
```

**IOS**

```
[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:kFIREventAddToCart parameters:@{
    kFIRParameterItemCategory:[parameters valueForKey:@"item_category"],
    kFIRParameterItemName:[parameters valueForKey:@"item_name"],
    kFIRParameterItemLocationID:[parameters valueForKey:@"item_location_id"],
    kFIRParameterCurrency:[parameters valueForKey:@"currency"],
    kFIRParameterValue:[parameters valueForKey:@"value"],
    kFIRParameterCoupon:[parameters valueForKey:@"coupon"],
    kFIRParameterItemID:[parameters valueForKey:@"item_id"],
    kFIRParameterQuantity:[parameters valueForKey:@"quantity"]
}];
```

In dashboard, We can see only item_name and value. please help.... thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing that your ***params*** object is a composed array with the similar values

```
{
    "item_category" : "t-shirts",
    "item_name" : "abc",
    "item_location_id" : "ChIJiyj437sx3YAR9kUWC8QkLzQ",
    "currency" : "USD",
    "value" : 3.99,
    "coupon" : "zz123",
    "item_id" : "p7654",
    "quantity" : 1
}
```

If that is the case then you are in the right way to create the event. But you are trying to see the event values in the **Parameter Reporting** section in the Firebase Console. I analysed based on the image you attached.

If you want to see the event values I recommend check the event dashboard report by clicking on the event name instead of the tab **Parameter Reporting**, follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57117671/3976000), it shows you an example of how Firebase Events are organized in the Dashboard Console.

[image]

I hope this helps you.

Comment: MArtin Daniel - just checked the predefined parameters are attached to event or not. in above scenario, item_name and value are automatically attached(refer screen shot) but not other parameter.

Comment: I think they are not showing because you are creating a report of a predefined event for [add_to_cart](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#public-static-final-string-add_to_cart) instead of viewing the event dashboard report. Check this [video](https://youtu.be/q4G2JJ_c5mQ) reference for google analytics for Firebase, they explain what you are trying to do in minute 3:00 approximately

Comment: Marthin Daniel - by default predefined parameter value should be show in event dashboard right

Comment: Yes it should, but when you say _default parameter value_ you refer to the value of that parameter (eg. `3.99`) or the predefined event `FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE`?

Comment: Yes Martin. I used like you mentioned. in parameter reporting section it is showing item_name and value for add_to_cart. not  showing other parameter. i don't know the reason.